# Get value from taxonomy field

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-object-model

Trying to get the selected value from a taxonomy field in sharepoint online using CSOM.
But when getting the taxonomyfieldvalue it is null, why?

```
        if (listitem.FieldValues.ContainsKey("Division")) // Returns true
        {
            TaxonomyFieldValue taxField = listitem["Division"] as TaxonomyFieldValue; // returns null !!
            pi.Division = taxField.Label;
        }
```

Comment: Did you load listitem with context.load() ?

Comment: Yes I have.
And I can get the values from other fields, it is only with the taxonomy field that I have problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get values as below:

**TaxonomyFieldValueCollection Test = (list.Items[0]["Field Name"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection);
var valuesList = (from v in Test select v.Label).ToList();**

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried to use TaxonomyFieldValueCollection instead of TaxonomyFieldValue but it also returns null.